# How to resolve entitlement error in ibm watson nlc?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, ibm-watson, nl-classifier

I am trying to train the IBM Watson NLC locally on my computer and after it trains for few mins it shows me this error

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "error" : "Entitlement error",
  "description" : "This user or service instance has the maximum number of classifiers."
}

(mytestenv) (base) C:\Users\mohana.kalyan\Desktop\ibm3\nlc-icd10-classifier>curl -i -u "apikey:#####################################" -F training_data=@C:\Users\mohana.kalyan\Desktop\ibm3\nlc-icd10-classifier\data\weather_data_train.csv -F training_metadata="{\"language\":\"en\",\"name\":\"ICD_classifier\"}" "https://gateway-fra.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-classifier/api/v1/classifiers"
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
X-Note: Gateway Ack

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
X-Backside-Transport: FAIL FAIL
Content-Type: application/json
X-XSS-Protection: 1
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
x-global-transaction-id: 0e7fa6da5c6a722c37a4550d
X-DP-Watson-Tran-ID: gateway-fra-dp02-933516557
X-DP-Transit-ID: gateway-fra-dp02-933516557
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;
Content-Length: 141
Date: Mon, 18 Feb 2019 08:51:56 GMT
Connection: close

{
  "code" : 400,
  "error" : "Entitlement error",
  "description" : "This user or service instance has the maximum number of classifiers."
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I indented your error message  by 4 spaces with <!-- language: lang-none --> so that it renders properly - [please see the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting.  Good luck!

Comment: Run the list classifiers method to check how many classifiers you already have, and if that is close to the limit for your plan, which I presume is lite.